# Angular directive data binding not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have been trying to write a shared directive for my angular apps that turns an input field into jquery timepicker.

I have two input fields, fromTime and toTime, and I want to update the toTime when the fromTime is changed.

My code is as follows:

**HTML**

```
<input type="text"
       time-picker="{ timeFormat: 'H:i'}"
       class="input-block-level"
       name="fromTime"
       ng-model="filter.fromTime"
       ng-change="update()" 
/>

<input type="text"
       time-picker="{ timeFormat: 'H:i'}"
       class="input-block-level"
       name="toTime"
       ng-model="filter.toTime"
       ng-change="update()" 
/>
```

**Directive**

```
sharedServices.directive('TimePicker', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
        time: "=ngModel"
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                    //Initialize the timepicker
        $(element).timepicker(scope.$eval(attrs.TimePicker));
                    //watch for changes
        scope.$watch('time', function(stuff) {
            console.log('some change', stuff);
        });
    }
};
});
```

**sharedServices included**

```
var roomsApp = angular.module("roomsApp", ["ngResource",'ui', 'sharedServices','ui.bootstrap']).config(function($routeProvider) { ...
```

The directive loads and the timepicker is initalized and attached to the element, but when I change the input fields nothing happens, not even the ng-change event that is attached to the element. The input fields are also empty when the page loads, even though the model is set to contain some value in the app's controller. Can anyone shed some light on the matter?

***Update**
http://plnkr.co/edit/t3BzShezEdh29ZAlI8ZI?p=preview this demonstrates my problem. Nothing is console logged when the date is changed

Comment: Show us the code where the directive is included. I see a few things that are really odd.

Comment: @TheHippo , done. The directive loads and the timepicker is initialized. But the binding between the scope and the directive is not working properly.

Comment: Please keep taking advantage of the ngModelController but not as a prop of your isolated scope, set it as a required controller injected as the forth argument of your linkibg function, overloading its $render method using its $viewValue and using its $setViewValue on your UI widget changes combined with $apply called on the scope.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**To fix the problem**

You'll need to listen to changes to the input field and update `scope.time`.

First change I did was to include Angular *after* jQuery, that way the `element` parameter will be a jQuery object.

Then listen to the change event and update `scope.time`. Wrap the call in `scope.$apply` to tell Angular that something has changed.

```
element.on('change', function () {
    scope.$apply(function () {
        scope.time = element.datepicker('getDate');
    });
});
```

<kbd>[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/pep9sPh0gp7xNuwHwFHu?p=preview)</kbd>

**Alternative approach**

Personally when writing directives that are applied on input elements I want to allow the user to use `ngModel` directive to keep the data in sync, since that is a known convention. By using ngModel you could also (optionally) use it's controller to add custom validation or other logic, e.g. parsers/formatters (not needed in this case).

By using the `$parse` service we can read/write data back to the ngModel field.

I also changed so that datetime options can be passed if needed.

Lastly I moved the first `datetime()` call to the compile function since that's the place where DOM manipulation should be made.

```
.directive("datetime", ['$parse', function($parse) {
  return {
      require: '?ngModel',
      restrict: 'A',
      compile: function (element, attrs) {
        var options = $parse(attrs.datetime)() || {};
        console.log('Passed options:', options);

        element.datepicker(options);

        // Return the link function
        return function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
          var getter, setter;

          // If the ngModel directive is used, then set the initial value and keep it in sync
          if (ngModel) {
            getter = $parse(attrs.ngModel);
            setter = getter.assign;

            console.log('ngModel directive used, setting initial value')
            element.datepicker("setDate", getter(scope));

            scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function(val, prev) {
              console.log('ngModel changed from', prev, 'to', val);
            });

            element.on('change', function () {
              console.log('change');
              var newValue = element.datepicker('getDate');
              scope.$apply(function () {
                setter(scope, newValue);
              });
            });
          }
        };
      }
  };
}])
```

And the directive is used like this:

```
<input type="text" datetime="{showButtonPanel: true}" ng-model="parentTime" />
```

<kbd>[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/1nqmW1az9u89tBecmnVQ?p=preview)</kbd>

Comment: What I don't understand is why the ng-model directive stopped working in the first place. I am in a situation where it works (binds input value to scope model) until I add a custom directive to the element. Then the binding isn't happening anymore. I just expected them to stack.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**
Here is a very rudimentary implementaion using jquery datepicker - http://plnkr.co/edit/4JZIWo6mJqg59F5o7xdh?p=preview

```
angular
.module("demo", [])
.directive("test", function() {
  return {
      restrict: 'A',
      scope: {
          time: "="
      },
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        console.log("scope.time:" + scope.time);
        $(element).datepicker();
        $(element).datepicker("setDate", scope.time);
      }
  };
})
.controller("demoCtl", function($scope){
  $scope.parentTime = new Date();
});
```

Have a look at [angular-ui calendar module](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-calendar).  If you don't want to use it, you can look at their code to help you.

---

Also, the way you set up your scope looks strange.  I think you want to bind you directive's `time` property, to a property managed by the directive's parent scope, not the ng-model.

try this

```
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
        time: "="
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                    //Initialize the timepicker
        $(element).timepicker(scope.$eval(attrs.TimePicker)); 
                    //watch for changes
        scope.$watch('time', function(stuff) {
            console.log('some change', stuff);
        });
    }
};
```

and use it

```
<input type="text"
       time-picker="{ timeFormat: 'H:i'}"
       class="input-block-level"
       name="toTime"
       time="filter.toTime"
       ng-change="update()" 
/>
```

also you don't need to wrap `attrs.TimePicker` in `$scope.eval`.

Comment: Using only "=" makes the "time" model undefined :/ and not using $scope.eval seems to ignore the options

Comment: looks like the wrong url - try this one: http://plnkr.co/edit/4JZIWo6mJqg59F5o7xdh?p=preview

Comment: ohhhhh, i see what the confusion is.  you can't watch the `scope.time` variable, because it isn't getting changed by the datepicker.  in the example i posted you see that i explicitly set the directive's `scope.time` variable, in the datepicker's `onSelect` event.